# New Tekkit - What to do with excess cobblestone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I have started playing the new Tekkit.  In the old Tekkit I created quarries, and used the energy condenser to turn masses and masses of useless cobblestone into useful materials.

In the new Tekkit there is no condenser.  So I have no idea what to do with the quickly growing piles of cobblestone I have from quarrying.

Is there a way to make all this cobblestone useful?  Is there something equivalent to the energy condenser?

Comment: Build something incredibly huge!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I started the new tekkit I also ran into this problem. Some things that i started doing with it were:

- Using the minium stone to turn it into clay then from clay to clay blocks then from clay blocks to iron. The conversion rate is terrible and it's a bit time consuming but it really helps clean up your chests.
- You can turn it into glass.  Glass is used in all sorts or recipes; the way you make glass is to pulverize it into sand, then toss the sand into a furnace.
- You can turn it into lava for [magmatic engines](http://tekkitlite.wikia.com/wiki/Magma_Crucible).

Answer (score 4):

You can recycle it for scrap ---> scrap boxes -----> free items!

Answer (score -1):

if you have enough cobble you can make diamonds out of it using philosopher's stone

Comment: That's the old Tekkit. There's no philosopher's stone anymore.

Comment: thats for sure a problem :P